# SQL Server: How to find unused fields in view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, view

Is there a way to identify fields in a view that are referenced by other objects in the database (e.g. procs, UDFs, other views)?

I have about 50 views that reference as its underlying data an external DB. The local views basically 'SELECT *' from the external DB tables.

We're changing the external DB and we need to figure out what fields are actually being used by the application that uses the views so we can setup the new external DB to contain only those fields we need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id), m.*
  FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES m
 WHERE m.definition like N'%my_view_name%'
```

This will allow you to search for view references, including specific column references.

### Background:

`SYSCOMMENTS`, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181381.aspx) and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines have NVARCHAR(4000) columns, while [SYS.SQL_MODULES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081%28SQL.90%29.aspx) definition column is NVARCHAR(MAX). So if "myViewName" is used at position 3998, it won't be found. `SYSCOMMENTS` does have multiple lines, but `ROUTINES` truncates.

Comment: +1 I gotta get better informed about the sys tables introduced in 2005

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

As OMG Poines points out when searching the definition you want to use modules instead

You probably still want the columns too so you'll want to join it to the sys.columns table

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id), c.*
  FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES m
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON m.object_id = c.object_Id
 WHERE m.definition like N'%externalDB%'
```

For thoes poor souls **Not** using 2005 or later you can still use the below.

To find the views for under the 4000 character limit

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
where 
VIEW_DEFINITION like '%externalDB%'
```

and if you want the columns from those views you can do the following

```
select c.* from 

information_schema.VIEWS vw
INNER JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS c
ON vw.Table_catalog = c.Table_catalog
and vw.TABLE_SCHEMA= c.TABLE_SCHEMA
and vw.TABLE_NAME= c.TABLE_NAME

where 
VIEW_DEFINITION like '%externalDB%'
```

However of course if those views reference local tables then you'll get those columns as well

**Note**: You might want to use SYSCOMMENTS instead of routines but if your search string is looking for something near a multiple of 4000 you'll still run into problems so that's an incomplete answer for those in SQL 2000

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click the view in Management Studio, you can choose "View Dependencies"
This should show you all other objects (stored procs, UDFs, other views) that depend on the selected view.

You'll then have to go through each and see what fields it actually uses, unfortunately.

As long as you don't also have dynamic SQL that calls the view directly from the app, this should help.